# Would a forked child always get same File ID as parent's file ID?

Tags: files, fork

This might be a naive question, but given in parent `open` call returned me File ID `4`.

Is it guaranteed that child process will **always** get a File ID of `4` as well ?

Comment: Is the parent calling `open` before or after `fork`?

Comment: Yep parent is the one that opens the file and then calls fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all **open** file IDs are copied to the child, when you fork.

See [man fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

Answer (score 1):

A successful `open` call returns the lowest number as a file descriptor that is not already in use.

So if `open` returns 4, it means that file descriptors 0-3 are already in use. As a `fork` gives the same file descriptors to the child, the child would also have fd 0-3 in use and fd 4 free, so two successful `open` calls in the parent and in the child immediately after a `fork` would return the same number. But if parent or child have opened or closed files after the `fork`, the numbers may be different.

In general, you should not rely on predicting the fd of an `open` call, unless you have a good reason and you are very certain that you can predict it correctly.